# Setting up two sepperate configuration but with the same domain

Tags: nginx

I have a question about nginx configuration.

On my server I normal deployment spot for my services and it is standard `/var/www/html` folder and a `git-lab` service.

Problem is that those two **"services"** stand on different configuration files.

To be more specific, exactly one line is problematic - defining server name so if I add line `server_name www.domain.com;` to both config files, one of the this is ignored and only `git lab` is binding to domain.

**Is there a way to bind that domain to two `nginx` config files?**

Comment: No. But rather than include your two configuration files into the `http` block, include them into a common `server` block instead. Look at the `nginx.conf` file to see where your existing files are included.

Comment: Hmm it would work, but they have different roots

Comment: At least one project will need to specify it's `root` within a `location`.